# Data binding not happening when the binded data is edited/updated in UI5

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, model, sapui5

I have a master-detail page which has a clone button. On clicking the clone button, the data of the first list item is put into a model (detailModel - which is declared in component.js) and a new screen is opened. The data of that list item is binded to some input fields. When any of that input field is updated/erased and then user navigates back without saving it and comes again on that page, that updated/erased field stays blank. I want that data to come in that field which was coming earlier but it is coming blank. Data in my model is also not changing. Below is the code :

Component.js :

```
this.detailModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        this.detailModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(this.detailModel, "detailModel");
```

Controller.js :

```
        /*eslint-disable no-console, no-alert */
    sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
        "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
        "hmel/TravelandGuestHouse/controller/formatter",
        "sap/m/MessageToast",
        "sap/m/MessageBox",
        "sap/m/Button",
        "sap/m/Dialog",
        "sap/m/Text",
        'sap/m/Label',
        'sap/m/TextArea'
    ], function (Controller, JSONModel, formatter, MessageToast, MessageBox, Button, Dialog, Text, Label, TextArea) {
        "use strict";
        return Controller.extend("hmel.TravelandGuestHouse.controller.CloneTravelRequest", {

            onInit: function () {
                this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                //for cloning request
                this.detailModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("detailModel");
                this.getView().setModel(this.detailModel, "detailModel");
                //for sending data to guest house screen
                this.getView().byId("date").setDateValue(new Date());
                this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
            },

            _handleRouteMatched: function (evt) {
                if (evt.getParameter("name") !== "CloneTravelRequest") {
                    return;
                }

                this.getView().invalidate();

                    var that = this;

                //fetching Train Names
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Non_sap_create_requests/odata/TravelPrpTrainDetails",
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        that.getView().getModel("Model").setProperty("/TravelPrpTrainDetails", data.value);
                        var tempModel = that.getView().getModel("detailModel");
                        var train = tempModel.getData().TrainName;
                        var trainKey = formatter.pickTrainKeyFromModel(data.value, train);
                        that.getView().byId("trainName").setSelectedKey(trainKey);
                        that.setLocations();
                        var nameofPass = tempModel.getData().NameOfPsngr;
                        if (nameofPass === "" || nameofPass === null) {
                            that.getView().byId("nameOfP").setValue(tempModel.getData().Requestee);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err.message);

                    }
                });

                var fdate = new Date();
                this.getView().byId("date").setDateValue(new Date());
                this.getView().byId("date").setMinDate(fdate);
            }



        });
    });
```

Comment: Change the value for `setDefaultBindingMode` to `sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay`. I suspect that if you set the binding mode to `OneWay`, the data from the model will only update the view and not vice versa. But when it's `TwoWay`, any changes to the view will also change the model. Refer https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.BindingMode

Comment: @Breakpoint I don't want to update the model. I want it to stay as it is when the user modifies some input without saving.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change to an [oDataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel) you can use the resetChanges method.

If you cant, you `ll have to do it a little bit more manually. Once the new windows pops up save the data the user will change and if he cancels it restore the saved data on the jsonDataModel.